# Xamarin Android - Making a Rest request with a complex parameter (object) throws exception, in .NET it works fine (Using channel factory)

Tags: android, wcf, rest, xamarin

I'm starting to use mono droid or Xamarin for Android, so, my idea was to reuse most of the code that I already use in .NET.

One of the things I need my android and ios application to do is to make calls to web services made available using wcf rest with json encoding.

So my code is simple:

```
WebHttpBinding webBinding = new WebHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.126.24:8025/Services/SecurityManagement");
ChannelFactory<ISecurityManagement> newFactory = new ChannelFactory<ISecurityManagement>(webBinding, endPointAddress);

newFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior() { DefaultOutgoingRequestFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json });

newFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new RestEndPointBehavior());

ISecurityManagement newProxy = newFactory.CreateChannel();
ValidateUserExistenceOutput output = newProxy.ValidateUserExistence(new ValidateUserExistenceInput() { Domain = "CRITICAL", Username = "myUserName" });
```

Simple enough to get me started (at least, that was my idea about mono, make in .net reuse in mono)

But when I run this code I get the following exception exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Loading...
07-25 10:43:40.922 E/mono    ( 1950): 
07-25 10:43:40.922 E/mono    ( 1950): Unhandled Exception:
07-25 10:43:40.922 E/mono    ( 1950): System.NotSupportedException: Conversion from the argument parameterType 'BusinessOrchestration.SecurityManagement.InputObjects.ValidateUserExistenceInput' is not supported
07-25 10:43:40.922 E/mono    ( 1950):   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.QueryStringConverter.ConvertValueToString (System.Object parameter, System.Type parameterType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-25 10:43:40.922 E/mono-rt ( 1950):   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.WebMessageFormatter+WebClientMessageFormatter.SerializeRequest (System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion messageVersion, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unkno07-25 10:43:40.922 E/mono    ( 1950):   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.WebMessageFormatter+WebClientMessageFormatter.SerializeRequest (System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion messageVersion, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-25 10:43:40.922 E/mono    ( 1950):   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior+ClientPairFormatter.SerializeRequest (System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion messageVersion, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-25 10:43:40.922 E/mono    ( 1950):   at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.CreateRequest (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientOperation op, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-25 10:43:40.922 E/mono    ( 1950):   at System.ServiceModel.MonoIn
07-25 10:43:40.922 E/mono-rt ( 1950): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NotSupportedException: Conversion from the argument parameterType 'BusinessOrchestration.SecurityManagement.InputObjects.ValidateUserExistenceInput' is not supported
07-25 10:43:40.922 E/mono-rt ( 1950):   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.QueryStringConverter.ConvertValueToString (System.Object parameter, System.Type parameterType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-25 10:43:40.922 E/mono-rt ( 1950):   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.WebMessageFormatter+WebClientMessageFormatter.SerializeRequest (System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion messageVersion, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-25 10:43:40.922 E/mono-rt ( 1950):   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior+ClientPairFormatter.SerializeRequest (System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion messageVersion, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-25 10:43:40.922 E/mono-rt ( 1950):   at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.CreateRequest (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientOperation op, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-25 10:43:40.922 E/mono-rt ( 1950):   at System.Servic
The program 'Mono' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I'm using the exact same code in a .NET 4.5 application and it works fine, it seems that its failing when converting the object to a string (a json string, I suppose).

Should it work directly in mono since it works in .NET?

Do you guys have services with complex input objects? 
What api do you use to make these calls?

Thanks ahead for all your help,

Luis Pinho

Comment: Did you solve this problem? i am facing the same problem not able to go one step forward.Googled  about this no resources Please help me if you have any idea.

Comment: similar problems are described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650314/mono-rest-service-not-supporting-post-method

Comment: This is a question from 2013 ???

Comment: yep, and since then mono did not fix REST support

Comment: Hi Hcorg, since I didn't get any help even from the Mono team, I decided to create new services with simple objects and Newtonsoft.Json library to handle the json decoding/encoding. I don't remember all the details since I no longer work on that project, sorry to hear that this is still happening.

Comment: yep, still. I too decided to leave WCF in Mono and I wrote my own HttpServer using HttpListener from System.Net :) Still it would be nice if somebody who knoiws mono would confirm it's a bug

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because some of the object used in your code hasn't been ported to Mono since they are Microsoft specific. There is some information here :
[Mono Class Status](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/class-status/)

For example, this namespace `Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement` used for `ISecurityManagement` in your code will probably never be ported.

To work on both Mono or .Net your code must follow the [.NET standard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/). It's a work in progress to harmonize Mono, .Net and .Net Core framework so they could compile common libraries and programs with less code differences.

Comment: error is not related to `ISecurityManagement` - same happens with already ported classes.

Comment: Hi Jimbot, that namespace was not used directly in the objects (how to you know I use that namespace?), we used to have that reference because we used the logging of the Microsoft enterprise libraries.

Comment: I look For ISecurityManagement on MSDN because i didn't know this interface and it's part of this namespace

Comment: Why not go easy way and use RestSharp or just HttpClient?